# Getting Zepto undefined error when using it in a page. How to resolve this?

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, undefined, zepto

I am running a script on a page where I include my `zepto.min.js` file first and then use it.

I get `Zepto undefined error.` Here is a code snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/my/website/zepto.min.js"></script>
var Zepto;
Zepto = window.Zepto;

main();
function main() {
    Zepto(document).ready(function($) {
    // My function to do things
}
```

When I call this I am getting `Undefined error.` Any idea to resolve this?

Comment: You need to check the order in which the scripts are included (`Zepto` script should be added before any operation is performed. refer: https://jsfiddle.net/srbh_ya16/qrsfh3yn/